# How to choose a UWP app as the default text editor for Git on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, uwp

I know how to specify the traditional win32 app as the default editor but UWP apps don't have an .exe file to use it in bash command. So is there another way to do it?

Comment: UWP apps that support command line execution will have an executable in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the one I need doesn't have the executable. Does this mean It's a dead end?

Comment: Yes, that means that the program doesn't support command line execution. I guess you could write a wrapper program that takes the file and calls LaunchFileAsync on it.